# Graphics program doesn't show output?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, bgi

I have 32 bit windows 7 system, in turbo c++ graphics.h is activated, my code compiled successfully, linked successfully but doesn't run and does not show any output how can I get it to work?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <graphics.h>
int main() {
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm,"C:\TC\BGI");
    putpixel(25,25,WHITE);
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

it is showing following:
Linking ...\SOURCE\NONAMEOO.EXE

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: #include<iostream.h>
#include<graphics.h>

int main()
{
int gd=DETECT,gm;
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\TC\BGI")
putpixel(25,25,WHITE)
closegraph()
return 0;
}

Comment: You should [edit] to post your code, not post it in comments. I did it for you, but remember that for next time.

Comment: ty...
is there any problem with code?

Comment: Is it C++? If yes, it's not supposed to be `#include <iostream.h>` but `#include <iostream>`. But I don't know if that will solve your problem.

Comment: program compiled successfully and when i run that it does not shows any error
Linking ...\SOURCE\NONAMEOO.EXE

Comment: @Push you are using very very old version of c++ with a compiler that is doomed to exist. As far as I know, it is only enforced by certain universities and definitely not by any employers. If that is the case, persuade them to change the compiler to somewhat newer version that atleast compiles a valid version of c++. This isn't valid code!

Comment: for which compiler should i go ?@AbhinavGauniyal